# implementing JSTL in Apache http server + JServ environment

Tags: apache, jstl

I am working in Apache http Server which using JServ Servlet engine.
Earlier the code is written in JSP itself.
Now I have to do refactoring and want to use JSTL.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this.

Regards
Amit

Answer (score 0):

JServ is *extremely* old, and quite profoundly obsolete.

If you want to use more modern JSP technologies, you're going to have to use a more modern servlet engine.